# How do i receive form data from the dynamically created JavaScript form fields into JSP?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

however, when i tried to get the values from the dynamically created form fields, i get null values from the form submission but not with the text fields created in html. Any help would be appreciated.

**small code snippet.**

```
            for (i=0;i<number;i++){


            // Append a node with a random text
            container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(("Sl.No ")));
            container.appendChild(document.createTextNode((i+1)));
            // Create an <input> element, set its type and name 
             attributes

            //name
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.type = "text";
            input.name = "name" + i;
            container.appendChild(input);

            //age
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.type = "text";
            input.name = "age" + i;
            container.appendChild(input);

            //book button
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "submit";
        input.name = "sbtn";
        input.value="Book";

        }
```

Comment: Use a same for loop in jsp also and read data like `request.getParameter("name"+i);` and `request.getParameter("age"+i);` and so on.

Comment: oh! perfect. it worked perfectly fine. thank you very much!!   can you please also help me to create dynamic option elements for options/choices using javaScript. thank you really. appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Below code gets dynamically created fields perfectly submitted.

HTML:

```
<form id="myForm" action="/" method="post">
<label id="authlabel">User Authentication method:</label>
<br>
<select id="authMethod" name="authmethod">
  <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
  <option value="userName">Name</option>
  <option value="userId">User ID</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="submit"></input>
</form>
```

JS:

```
const myForm = document.querySelector('#myForm');

document.querySelector('#authmethod').addEventListener('change', function(event){
    let authInput = document.createElement('input');
    authInput.name = event.target.value;
    myForm.insertBefore(authInput, event.target.nextSibling);
});
```

If, for some reason, it doesn't work for you, would you submit your HTML and full javascript context?

Comment: hey, thank you for the response. i appreciate it. your method could have also worked out but i chose @Sudhir Ojha 's answer as it is simple for me to edit. thank you for your help though.